# Custom binding handler, render binding from string template

Tags: knockout.js, ko-custom-binding

I making a custom binding with a row template that should be optional. If the user does not supply a template id i want to use a default one, but it does not reside in a script tag in body, it's just a string on the options literal.

How can i use a string as template?

the default template should be really easy something like this

```
<span data-bind="text: name"></span>
```

I've tried the ko.renderTemplate but it does only take id's to script tags

```
ko.renderTemplate(template, bindingContext.createChildContext(data), null, row, "replaceChildren");
```

**Update**
Just got a notification about this question, and saw that there were people suggestion injecting the template to the dom and use the standard script tag provider. But this does not take into account that the user can override the default template source (Common scenario with single plage applications. I use this way, that first tries the default template provider and then fallbacks to the string template source like this

```
var engines: {}
var renderTemplate = function (element, template, data, bindingContext) {
    var engine = engines[template];

    var success = false;
    do {
        try {
            ko.renderTemplate(template, bindingContext.createChildContext(data), engine, element, "replaceChildren");
            success = true;
            engines[template] = engine;
        } catch(err) {
            if (engine != null)
                throw "Template engine not found";

            engine = { templateEngine: stringTemplateEngine };
        }

    } while (!success)
};
```

Full code and stringTemplateEngine code can be found here
https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Combobox/blob/master/src/knockout.combobox.js#L297

Comment: Just to clarify, the template itself, and not the name of the template, exists in a string, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To render templates from strings you will need to write a custom template source as described [here.](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/10/ko-13-preview-part-3-template-sources.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Couldn't he just inject the string into the DOM with jQuery .html()? This seems easier.

Comment: Totally but I got the impression he didn't want to that.

Comment: If you ask me this is nicer... Works really nice from custom bindings

Comment: The best and smallest usage of this is not covered in the article it self, its found in the comments http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/VZmsy/